# How to make react-popper tooltip interactive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popper.js, react-popper

I am using the `usePopper` hook provided by `react-popper` to create tooltips. My usage is based on [this official example](https://popper.js.org/react-popper/v2/#example).

I would like users to be able to interact with the tooltip (e.g., select text or click a button in the tooltip). However, the tooltip currently hides on any attempt of interacting with it.

Is there a way to allow user interactions with a react-popper-based tooltip (it seems, for example, that Tippy.js has [an option for allowing interactivity](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/#interactivity))?

Comment: I tried react-popper aswell. I could not get it working properly... In the end, I just created my popover component with tippyjs-react (https://github.com/atomiks/tippyjs-react). It has all the functionality from the 'normal' tippyjs that you can declare as props. You can indeed use the hideOnClick and interactive prop for different states of the popover. Works like a charm.